# Laravel Livewire Same Component Two Items Sync in One Page

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, livewires, laravel-livewire

I made `follower` component.

If visitor follows a author, then component will show `Following` and if not, it will show `Follow`.

I put `follower` component in two places of page.

-follower component.

```
<div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="follow_btn" wire:click="toggle">{{$following? 'Following': 'Follow'}}</a>
</div>
```

public $following = true;
public $post;

```
public function mount($post)
{
    $this->post = $post;
}
public function render()
{
    if(Auth::check()&&user()->isFollowing($this->post->user))
    {
        $this->following = true;
    }else {
        $this->following = false;
    }
    return view('livewire.following');
}
public function toggle()
{
    user()->toggleFollow($this->post->user);
}
```

I am using this component in two places in one page.

```
<livewire:follower :post="$post">
...
<livewire:follower :post="$post">
```

When I click one component, it was toggled and worked well.

But the other component keeps old state.

How can I sync them?

Thank you

Comment: Have you try pass a different key to both component? like :key="first-{{ $post->id }}" and :key="second-{{ $post->id }}"

Comment: To sync them ??

Comment: @lovecoding Could you sync them? I have the same drawback.

Comment: @user2851148 Check this answer please. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66292844/13431339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to emit refresh event.

```
protected $listeners = [
     'followingRefresh' => '$refresh',
];

public function mount($post)
{
    $this->post = $post;
}
public function render()
{
    if(Auth::check()&&user()->isFollowing($this->post->user))
    {
        $this->following = true;
    }else {
        $this->following = false;
    }
    return view('livewire.following');
}
public function toggle()
{
    user()->toggleFollow($this->post->user);
    $this->emit('followingRefresh'); //emit event
}
```

Hope this helps someone.